# Using puts method in Ruby to get the same output as printing in a loop

Tags: ruby, loops, methods, puts

thanks for clicking. I'm learning Ruby from this [tutorial](http://prepwork.appacademy.io/coding-test-1/introduction-to-programming-3/).

And here's a bit of code for a method that gives square values.

```
def first_square_numbers(number_of_squares)
 squares = []

 idx = 0
 while idx < number_of_squares
  squares.push(idx * idx)
  idx = idx + 1
 end

 return squares
end

puts("How many square numbers do you want?")
number_of_desired_squares = gets.to_i
squares = first_square_numbers(number_of_desired_squares)

idx = 0
while idx < squares.length
 puts(squares[idx])
 idx = idx + 1
end

# Output:
#   How many square numbers do you want?
#   7
#   0
#   1
#   4
#   9
#   16
#   25
#   36
```

My question is, in order to print the output, instead of this code:

```
 idx = 0
 while idx < squares.length
  puts(squares[idx])
  idx = idx + 1
 end
```

Can I just put this?

```
puts(squares)
```

I tried it and got the same result but I'm not sure which is "more correct" and why.

Thanks!

Comment: So you are a good student who loves exploration. Yes, `puts` prints arrays one element a line, so your code is absolutely correct. As you go on learning Ruby, you'll find that all the loops are unnecessary, and we can write the whole script in just 3 lines.

Answer (score 2):

```
puts squares
```

is, without doubts, more correct since it's an idiomatic Ruby. Another option is to use the `each` iterator method:

```
squares.each { |n| puts n }
```

But in this case `puts` is enough.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you should use `puts squares` instead (no need for the parentheses here either) because it's more readable and cleaner and well there's no need to re-invent the wheel etc.

Although your overall code works fine, in Ruby it would be better to do something like:

```
puts "How many squares do you want?"
puts (1..gets.to_i).map {|i| i**2 }
```

***How it works...***

Suppose the user enters `7`:

```
1..gets.to_i #creates a range from 1 to the user's input
  #=> 1..7

map {|i| i**2 } #takes each element from 1..7, squares it and puts in an array
  #=> [1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49]

puts #prints out each element of the above array on a new line:
  #=>
  #1
  #4
  #9
  #16
  #25
  #36
  #49
```

For further information see documentation for [Range](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Range.html) and [Enumerable#map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-map).

Answer (score 0):

If you call `puts` with an array, it will print out the elements line by line. The behavior is exactly the same as your loop version.

See the documents [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/IO.html#method-i-puts)

> If called with an array argument, writes each element on a new line.

P.S. It's more practical to use built-in iteration methods to operate on all the elements in an array:

```
squares.each do |square|
  puts(square)
  # possibly some other operations on the element
end
```